# How to "clean" what is sent to the table of contents? (Remove index etc.)

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, indexing, marginpar

I want to use markup commands such as `\pkg{classicthesis}` that not only typeset the entry, but that have side-effects such as adding a margin note or index entry.  (See the example below.)

My problem is that I would like to be able to use these in sectioning commands `\chapter{The \pkg{classicthesis} Package}`, but doing so sends the extra stuff to the `.toc` file as well, which can cause problems when the table of contents is formatted.

**Question:** *How can I clean everything but the text (and formatting information) from what is sent to the `.toc` file?*

I know that I could do something like `\chapter[The \pkg*{classicthesis} Package]{The \pkg{classicthesis} Package}` where I define the starred form to omit the extra info, but this means unnecessarily duplicating the contents.

Note: I am doing this for a class and have no problem redefining `\chapter` etc. to do the cleaning, I just need the internals.

Here is a MWE.  In the second case, the index command appears both in the section header and in the ToC: the latter introducing an undesired entry in the index and the marginpar also appears in the ToC.  There are usually workarounds for each individual issue (in this case the `scrindex` package solves the index problem and one could disable `\marginpar` in the toc), but I would still like a general solution.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{scrindex} % This will fix the index issue.
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{makerobust}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\newcommand*{\pkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\marginpar{\texttt{#1}}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\pkg*[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\MakeRobustCommand\pkg

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The Problem}
\section[The \pkg*{classicthesi} Package]{The \pkg{classicthesis} Package}
This works, but is error-prone and violates the DRY principle.
\section{The \pkg{classicthesis} Package}
This fails because the indexing commands are sent to the .toc file.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you are using a KOMA-Script class you are also using package KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`. So you can simply use `\BeforeStartingTOC` to redefine the macros until they are used at the `toc` file and local to the `toc` file:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{scrindex} % This will fix the index issue.
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{makerobust}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\newcommand*{\pkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\marginpar{\texttt{#1}}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\pkg*[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\MakeRobustCommand\pkg

\makeindex

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\pkg\csname \SuffixName\pkg*\endcsname
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The Problem}
\section{The \pkg{classicthesis} Package}
This works.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

To completely *deactivate* a single argument macro use something like

```
\makeatother
\BeforeStartingTOC{%
   \let\pkg\@firstofone
}
\makeatletter
```

You may find more information about `\BeforeStartingTOC` at page 238 of the current [English KOMA-Script manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf). The whole documentation of package `tocbasic` may be found at chapter 10 of the same manual.

AFAIK their is no possibility to just say *deactivate all macros*, so the answer to this question is still open. But if I correctly understand your question, deactivation of `\pkg` is not really what you want. You still want `\pkg` to be `\texttt`.

Another solution may be to deactivate `\index` and `\marginpar`:

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{%
  \renewcommand*{\index}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\marginpar}[2][]{}%
}
```

instead of redefining `\pkg`.

Comment: That will work, but requires special casing each problematic command.  Maybe this is the best answer possible, but what I am looking for is some sort of semi-magic command `\getonlythetex{}` that discards everything except the text.  I.e. is there some way of  checking whether a macro expands to nothing (only side-effects) without actually expanding it (and thereby triggering the side-effect), subsequently discarding the macro.  The more I think about though, the less likely I think that another solution exists.

Comment: @mfborbes: I don't think, that such a solution can exists, because sometimes an argument of a macro still should be set (e.g. `\pkg`) and sometimes it should be removed together with the macro (e.g. `\index`). And automatism for this needs manual declaration. Declaration is the thing I do at my answer using `\let` or `\renewcommand`.